# How can I find which account I used for downloading my iOS apps?

Tags: ios-appstore, accounts

I use three different accounts for downloading from the App Store, each in a different country.

When there is an update, I have to connect to the correct App Store to download the update, but sometimes I can't remeber from which store an app was downloaded and so I need to connect to each one in turns.

I would like to be able to find the account I used to download an app so that I can connect to the correct App Store immediately. Also, this would enable me to verify if the app already exists in the App Store of my main account and buy/download it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iTunes you can simply right click the app in question and choose Get Info. On the summary tab you can see the account used to purchase the app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would log in to each account and check your purchase history. That seems like the most direct way to me. [This Apple article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2727) has details on how to do this.

Comment: I was hoping the information was available somewhere inside the iTunes Library, just not displayed at the GUI, and that I could find that reading some file.

Comment: And the purchase history is separated in invoices, repeats the app for each update I downloaded and mixes iOS apps with OSX apps.