# Is there a way to filter or sort my iOS Apps by Account which was used to purchase them?

Tags: ios-appstore, accounts

Related to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/how-can-i-find-which-account-i-used-for-downloading-my-ios-apps):

I have used several accounts to purchase/get for free a lot of iOS Apps. I'd like to sort them by account that was used to purchase them, since clicking through all those Apps with the Information Window is infeasible.

The problem I really want to solve is the following:

Sometimes, there are updates for apps purchased from other country stores (other accounts) - these show up in iTunes, but only as nonzero number next to the Apps Category.

E.g.: Today, if I use my main account (Austria) then I see no update notifications, but when I use my US account there is the number 3 next to the Apps category. I just want to find out what all the accounts are that I might need to check. (Yes, there are some that might have slipped my mind)

Answer (score 1):

I've multiple accounts as well. I'd like to use free US apps as well that they don't provide on my countries App Store. Neat trick.

Anyway. Unfortunately there isn't a sort option existing in iTunes like the one you've asked since Apple won't care about our situation in general. Most users will only have a single account.

Also there isn't a third-party app for that.

So we're stuck with changing accounts all the time. But one advice that I can give you is that check some of those apps that you've downloaded with your US account in Austria store. Maybe those developers placed theirs apps in Austria store as well as of now. Deleting the old one and re-downloading it will keep your app library more organized.

Answer (score 1):

With your apps in the main iTunes window (this still works with multiple windows but only if the apps list is in the original iTunes window), Get Info and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> which will cycle you through to the Get Info for the next app in the list. I basically stared at the account information and pressed <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> multiple times and tried not to blink. When the account info changes, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> slowly to get back to it. (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> & <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> are the keyboard shortcuts for Next and Previous, the buttons shown in the Get Info pane.)

---

If that's too lame for you, then you can try hacking together a script. A few years back, I downloaded an AppleScript or Automator workflow that gave me a text file list of all my apps and the account used to purchase each one. I've searched my computer and the web for the original to no avail. I do remember that I had to tweak the script to get that data, but in the absence of the original file, I am unable to reconstruct it.

It is possible to get all of the Get Info window data via Automator. If you want to try yourself, you can download an iTunes script that outputs your music file data and start tweaking it yourself to get what you want.

Google can answer most of your questions on how to do that if you have the patience.