# Transferring app account ownership

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, accounts

Is it possible to transfer an app from one app store account to another? I want to be able to update some apps that my father bought on his account that are currently on my iPhone, but I'm pretty sure that I'd have to transfer those apps to my account first. Do I need to transfer the apps to be able to update them? If so, how would I do that?

### Edits

From looking at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/50909/22362), I guess that the only option that I have is to transfer app account ownership to my account in order to update those apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it's stated in the linked question, this isn't possible... As a matter of fact, a lot of users are suffering from this issue and some of them even have [contacted Apple about it](http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-1-forum/58712-moving-purchased-apps-another-apple-id.html#post403386) and here is what Apple said:

> ... they told me to reset my password so that both userids have the same
>   password. When you get notification that an app is to be upgraded, you
>   will get a prompt to enter your password. The prompt will indicate
>   which userid you bought the app under. I have not had to logon to
>   either id's to see which apps are updated. But you do have to log off
>   and logon in iTunes to see the apps you purchased under that specific
>   userid.

I have multiple accounts myself (one for the US App Store and one for my own country) and I switch accounts in the **Settings < Store** menu in order to get to donwload/update apps from the different stores.
In my opinion, that's the only way to get/update apps bought with different accounts.